# My domain name is marked private, but who.is still lists it with my personal information

Tags: domains, whois, privacy

I registered a new domain name at my provider and told them afterwards, after I found out that my personal information was listed, to make it private. So they did that.

I just checked who.is and put my domain name in the search box only to find out that my personal information is still listed. This is something I don't want!

How does this work? Do I have to look every who.is site to check if the changes were made?

Comment: You may be seeing a cached response? Check with your registrar that the "private registration" was implemented.

Comment: @w3dk Many of these sites will collect whois data ASAP if not immediately. Some will collect it per request. Who.is is the former (last I looked) and therefore the OPs data is in their database for as long as they want to keep it. So as for the OP, the only solution is to contact the site owner.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the web host is actually not the registrar and is reselling the registrations. In this case, it is quite possible that they modified the domain from their system/API of registrar, but the API call was not made correctly or perhaps, not made at all. Update your message with the hosting provider and provide the link to the whois records for them to view. It is likely they are unaware of the error.